# Getting (and appending) correct file path in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a previously defined file name in a string format, and a previously defined variable called value. I am trying to store a variable that looks like:

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Value_Validation_Report

with the syntax below, I instead get:

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Value\ _Validation_Report

```
target_dir= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(FileName))
ValidationReport=os.path.join(target_dir,value,"_Validation_Report")
print ValidationReport
```

Every other combination I have tried leads to an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `value` is a `String`, you must concatenate that with `"_Validation_Report`

```
target_dir= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(FileName))
ValidationReport=os.path.join(target_dir,value + "_Validation_Report")
print ValidationReport
```

`os.path.join` will add a separator (which depends on the operating system) between each string you give it. To avoid this, simply put your `value` and `"_Validation_Report"` strings together as one `String`. See more about [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: Jamie you are a rockstar! Thanks for the fast response.